# How to invoke one more java process from java program

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I want to execute **mvn exec:java** command from a java program.

I tried Runtime and ProcessBuilder API but unbale to acheive.

Please help me in this problem.

Regards,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Most probably java can not find "mvn" executable. Maintaing PATH variable and finding executables is a function of a command line shell (cmd, bash, etc..). Runtime.exec() does not use your shell.

You need to supply full path to executable for Runtime.exec() to find it.